# Spring MVC (Java) to integrate with AWS Cognito (user authentication)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've been working on my personal project -- Spring MVC Application which integrates with AWS Cognito. I have created user pool and linked the pool to a federated identity (not using Facebook or Google to authenticate). Since the SDK that Amazon provides is for Android development in Java, CognitoUserPool is asking to add "android.context.Context" as one of the arguments. Is there any way to get context that works on Spring MVC to integrate with AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using wrong SDK. Amazon provides SDK for Java and SDK for Android. Make sure, you are using the right one.

Comment: I looked for it but I cannot find the exact one that I can refer to in order to execute sign up and sign in. Is there any link that I refer to?

Comment: @Suguru It should be [https://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip](https://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip) or if you are using Maven [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.89](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.89). I hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'll give it a try.